# Error in glm.fit when using a tweedie distribution with log link

Tags: r, glm, tweedie

When running `glm` in R using tweedie and log link, I run into

> "Error in glm.fit ... NA/NAN/INF in x"

I have tried using different distributions and links. I have also tried adding 1 to the response because it is insurance data with lots of 0s.

I have already checked for na's, nan's, and inf values and have none in my dataset (or have already corrected for them).

Here is the code I have:

```
fit = glm(y~x, data=data1,
             family=tweedie(var.power=1.6, link.power=0), weights=weights)
```

Comment: can you share your data? does a tweedie distribution support using weights (just curious)?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the data. I don't see why it wouldn't be able to, I think the weights are used to "weight" each observations contribution to the loglikelihood summation. Something like weight(i)*loglikelihood(i).

Comment: I do wonder, would it have anything to do with the "start" input in the glm function? I think that gives starting values for the iterative least squares algorithm...or am i wrong?

Comment: good question, I am out of my depth here but there might be an answer on cross validated that might help you.

Comment: Check your `x` variable.  Is one of the values not finite (`Inf`) or not a number (`NaN`)?

Comment: I have yes, I can confirm that is not the issue. I think it had to do with starting values in the GLM. I will run a few tests to confirm this today.